# Nvidia driver doesn't work after successful installation

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have an Asus k401 notebook with an Nvidia GeForce 940m. I've added the graphics ppa and installed the most recent version (nvidia-367). The installation was successful and, according to the Additional Drivers app, the driver is currently being used. However when I run `nvidia-detector` the result is `none`. When I try to open nvidia-settings, I receive the following messages

```
** Message: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

The nvidia-settings gui opens but doesn't have all the options it should have. I've also tried to install the driver from nvidia website but that did not work too.

An interesting fact is the when I run `sudo prime-select nvidia` or `intel`, the command works. In other words, nvidia-prime is working.

Anyone has any idea how to solve this issue?

My Ubuntu version is 16.04. The result of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` is the following:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
    Kernel driver in use: i915
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_367, nvidia_367_drm
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Did you try the stable 361 driver? 367 is not supported yet.

Comment: And also try to disable SecureBoot in bios.

Comment: SecureBoot is already disabled. I tryed the 364 driver and also didn't work. I will try the 361.

Comment: If the command line `prime-select` works, it means that it works. The problem may be with `nvidia-settings` GUI.

Comment: 361 also does not work. I do not believe the problem is only with `nvidia-settings`. The result of `nvidia-smi` is `Unable to determine the device handle for GPU 0000:04:00.0: Unknown Error`.

Comment: Stupid question: you rebooted?

Comment: Yes. In every single driver version I tested, I rebooted after the installation.

Comment: You can't install an older version - they made every older version depend on the 367 version so you are no longer able to go back to a working version. How stupid is that?